# Attempting to get this to print 1,2,3,...[value] in assembly

Tags: assembly, printf, nasm

[value] is equal to 5. I've got it to where it prints

```
25367 ,
```

instead of

```
1,2,3,4,5,
```

I've commented my code below to show what I'm trying to do.

```
printnum:                       ;this section sets up the starting values
    mov edi, 0                  ;start at 0
    mov bl, [value]             ;"preserve" value
    jmp printnumloop            ;go to printnumloop


printnumloop:
     ;call  correct             ;for debugging to see if it reached here  
     cmp    edi,  [value]       ; compare the counter variable to [value]
     jle    actuallyprint       ; if less than or equal to, jmp to print
     jmp    menu                ;else, should be done printing, back to menu

actuallyprint:

    lea rdi, [rel formatnum]        ;loads "%d",0
    mov rsi, [rel edi]              ;should load value in edi
    mov al, 0
    call    printf                  ;prints number

    ;call   correct                  ;for debugging (check if here)

    lea     rdi, [LC8]               ;loads comma
    mov     eax, 0
    call    printf                   ;prints comma
    add     edx, 1                   ;add 1 to edx to print/check the next #

    call    printnumloop             ;calls printnumloop to check if <=value
```

New code! Progress! Get an infinte loop of numbers printed! The numbers appear negative though when adding 1, so it keeps going since it's jle after cmp counter to [value]. Tried inc edi too.

```
printnum:
    mov edi, 0                  ;start at 0
    jmp actuallyprint   


printnumloop:
    add edi, 1  
    cmp     edi, [value]
    jle     actuallyprint
    jmp menu


actuallyprint:

    mov esi, edi    
    lea rdi, [rel formatnum]
    mov al, 0
    call    printf

    lea rdi, [LC8]
    mov     eax, 0
    call    printf

    jmp printnumloop
```

Comment: `rdi` and `edi` are the same register so using `edi` after you loaded `rdi` is wrong. Also, you seem to have the number already in `edi`, it's not a memory reference. As such you just need `mov esi, edi; lea rdi, [rel formatnum]`.

Comment: Where does `edi` get incremented?

Comment: If rdi and edi are the same, when I load the LC8 comment into rdi it wipes out edi, huh?

Answer (score 0):

Changed the counter variable to ebx and it works flawlessly.